# Hibernate mapping order-by ignore case

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Hibernate mapping order-by ignore case.

```
<set name="documents" inverse="true" order-by="DOC_NAME"  cascade="all-delete-orphan">
    <key column="ID"/>
    <one-to-many class="com.abac.Document" />
</set>
```

This code returns the ordered list of document but fail in case of capital letters and small letters.

Is there any settings in hibernate mapping that ignore case in order-by.

using oracle db.

Comment: what database are you using ? try with show SQL flag true and analyze the query generated by hibernate

Comment: Please try `order-by="DOC_NAME DESC"`.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan but that will do the same as inverse="true" placed already. Here we need some TO_UPPER or TO_LOWER function

Comment: Correct! i got it wrong.

Comment: Try using something like order-by=lower("DOC_NAME"). Its just a guess, see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `UPPER` or `LOWER` in `order-by` like this. I have used it before and this is what i have done at that time, as far as i remember correctly.

```
order-by="UPPER(DOC_NAME)"
```

And you can have a look at the `sort` property as well at this link [sort property](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-sorted)